# Why are virtual assignment operators "a can of worms"?

Tags: c++

My textbook says that virtual assignment operators "opens a new can of worms beyond the scope of the tutorial".

> It is possible to make the assignment operator virtual. However,
> unlike the destructor case where virtualization is always a good idea,
> virtualizing the assignment operator really opens up a bag full of
> worms and gets into some advanced topics outside of the scope of this
> tutorial. Consequently, we are going to recommend you leave your
> assignments non-virtual for now, in the interest of simplicity.

What does this mean? Can you explain what the problems the book refers to with a small example? Why are virtual assignment operators special?

Comment: In general, assignment operator and inheritance together is a bad idea, there is so much that can go wrong if not properly accounted for, for instance object truncation. And that's *before* throwing virtual inheritance into the mix, which multiplies the special cases to get right.

Comment: would be good if you could summarize or provide a link to the example the tutorial is about for context

Comment: edited, asking for links or off-site resources is considered offtopic

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ object slicing".

Comment: Okay, I will, thanks @ThomasMatthews ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take the classic shape example:

```
class Shape
{
  public: virtual bool operator==(const Shape & s) const = 0;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
  public: bool operator==(const Shape & s) const
  { /*...*/ }
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
  public: bool operator==(const Shape & s) const
  { /*...*/ }
};
```

Now comes the fun part.

```
Rectangle r;
Circle c;
Shape * p_shape1 = &r; // This is legal.
Shape * p_shape2 = &c; // So is this.

// What happens here????
if (r == *p_shape2)
{
  //...
}
```

IMHO, operators should not be inherited.  There is no guarantee that Child1's operators will be passed Child1 instances;  They could be passed Child` or Child3 or even GrandChild1 instances.

Comment: It's even more interesting with assignment!

Comment: That’s nothing specific to operators. The function is defined to take a `Shape const&` argument and that’s all it can assume. Writing a virtual equality operator generally involves `dynamic_cast`. In any case, though, the OP was asking about the assignment operator.